# React Native Pass properties on navigatorIOS pop

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigator

I'm using NavigatorIOS on my react native app. I want to pass some properties when navigating back to previous route.

An example case: I'm in a form page. After submitting data, I want to go back to the previous route and do something based on the submitted data

How can I pass the state variables of my current element to the previous route when using pop to go back?

Any code sample would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic example of what is trivially solved with [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) or some other centralized state store.

Without that, is the behavior that you go "back" via NavigatorIOS's `pop` method?  It takes no arguments, so I doubt that'll work at all.

The best you could do is only use `push`, where you can define the `route` which could contain the form data in `passProps`:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  title: NavigatorIOSExample.title,
  component: NavigatorIOSExamplePage,
  backButtonTitle: 'Custom Back',
  passProps: { formData },
});
```

But really, use Redux.